# How to add canonical header and 301 redirect in nginx

Tags: http, nginx, header, canonical-link

I'm trying to add a canonical header in nginx on a location that is already returning a 301. I'm adding a canonical to the destination URL as the canonical link is more important to users than the actual URL showing in Google. I can't see the canonical response header coming through when checking dev tools?

Current nginx routing is set up as

```
location ~* '^/folder/another-folder/important-document.pdf' {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/docs/destination-url;
}
```

and I've tried adding the canonical URL as follows:

```
location ~* '^/folder/another-folder/important-document.pdf' {
  return 301 $scheme://$host/docs/destination-url;
  add_header Link "<$scheme://$http_host/folder/another-folder/url>; rel=\"canonical\"";
}
```

The second example has been in prod for around 2 weeks and I'm still seeing the .PDF showing in Google organic results and no response headers in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

The first regular expression location that matches the URI will process the request, so if you have an ambiguous location block above this one, it will prevent your rule being taken. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Either move the `location` block higher up in your `server` block, so that it is encountered first.

If you are trying to match a single URI, use an exact match location, which always takes highest precedence irrespective of its position within the `server` block. For example:

```
location = /folder/another-folder/important-document.pdf { ... }
```